# testcafe seems to not be compatible with last version of logSymbol

Tags: testing, automation, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

I try to use last version of LogSymbol, that provides a breaking change due to esm compatibility.

But using Gherkin-testcafe and then testcafe, it seem compilation failed due to no esm support.

I don't why I get this error from testcafe:
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SeUTg.png)

if I try to override testcafe typescript compilation options but I get this error:
[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5G2OY.png)

A sample of project with my issue is avalaible here: https://github.com/bbutel/testcafe-logSymbol-issues

Comment: Welcome to stakeoverflow, take a [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to understand how so works. [guide - how can I ask](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions), we are here to help you out but need some efforts before posting a question [research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) and also check out a [things to keep in mind to post a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), for any other help [visit](https://stackoverflow.com/help/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TestCafe cannot work with pure ESM modules like `logSymbols` because built-in TestCafe compilers transpile all test code to the `commonjs` format, which in not supported by the latest version of `logSymbols`. Thus, to solve the issue, you need to use the `commonjs` version of the `logSymbols` module.

Comment: thx a lot for your answer.
Do you plan to make testcafe compatible with ESM module ?

Comment: We have no plans to do it in the near future

Comment: Thx a lot. Can I create a feature ticket on your side ? and maybe you will think about it :)

Comment: Sure, please use the following link: https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/new?assignees=&labels=&template=feature_request.md

Comment: thx. Here the issue: https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/6372